# 3 x 5 ft banner, what size does my photographs need to be?

Tags: images

Help!  I have a 3 x 5 ft banner I'm making but I'm not sure about the photograph they want included.  How do I know if the photograph will work?  Need advice ASAP!  From resolution to size of image...

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE, Olive! Do you know where the banner is being printed at? Most printers can provide you with their recommended minimum specs.

Answer (score 1):

The size of your photograph will be be different depending on the DPI you are printing at. DPI = dots per inch. So if you are printing at 300 DPI you will need:

```
300 dpi * 5 feet * 12 inches = 18,000px
300 dpi * 3 feet * 12 inches = 10,800px
```

However, this is WAY more than 14mp! I recommend printing at 72 DPI for large prints, it will still look fine and your image will actually fit.

```
72 dpi * 5 feet * 12 inches = 4,320px
72 dpi * 3 feet * 12 inches = 2,592px
```

This translates to about 14mp.